# "Site Can't Be Reached" Error For Nodejs Lambda Microservice Serverless Express.js With Compression

Tags: node.js, express, compression, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to understand how the [compression](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression) nodejs library does and why it's giving me issues in this situation.

My code is meant to be run on AWS Lambda running nodejs 6.10. Here's my index.js that basically just sets up "awsServerlessExpress".

```
'use strict';

const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express')
const app = require('./app')
const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app)

exports.handler = (event, context) => awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context);
```

Then my app.js looks like this:

```
const awsServerlessExpressMiddleware = require('aws-serverless-express/middleware')
const compression = require('compression')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(compression())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext())

const emptyRouteHandler = require('./src/routes/empty-route');

app.get('/', emptyRouteHandler);

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send({
    "Output": "Hello World!"
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

My app is then exposed as a GET rest endpoint. However, when I try to do aa request that gives a large response it gives me a "Site Can't Be Reached" error.

[image]

When I comment out the line `app.use(compression())` and do the exact same request everything works, and and I get the expected response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ticker": "BNBBTC",
      "volume": {
        "volumePastOneMinute": 3342.97,
        "volumePastFiveMinute": 12833.57,
        "volumePastOneday": 2631570.63,
        "normalizedVolumePastOneMinute": 3342.97,
        "normalizedVolumePastFiveMinute": 2566.714,
        "normalizedVolumePastOneday": 1827.4796041666666
      },
      "price": {
        "priceChangePast1min": -9.000000000000761e-7,
        "priceChangePast5min": -0.000006000000000000146,
        "normalizedPriceChange1min": -9.000000000000761e-7,
        "normalizedPriceChange5min": -0.0000012000000000000292,
        "priceChange24hr": 0.0000459,
        "highLowDiff24hr": 0.00006839999999999993,
        "weightedAvgPrice24hr": 0.00162003
      },
      "recommendation": {
        "toBuyOrNotToBuy": "Don't Buy",
        "volumeHeatRating": "Hot",
        "volumeRatio1minTo1day": null,
        "volumeRatio5minTo1day": null,
        "volumeRatio1minTo5min": 1.302431825283222
      }
    },
    {
      "ticker": "BNBUSDT",
      "volume": {
        "volumePastOneMinute": 12528.64,
        "volumePastFiveMinute": 33792.58,
        "volumePastOneday": 3743812.16,
        "normalizedVolumePastOneMinute": 12528.64,
        "normalizedVolumePastFiveMinute": 6758.5160000000005,
        "normalizedVolumePastOneday": 2599.8695555555555
      },
      "price": {
        "priceChangePast1min": -0.035199999999999676,
        "priceChangePast5min": -0.04209999999999958,
        "normalizedPriceChange1min": -0.035199999999999676,
        "normalizedPriceChange5min": -0.008419999999999917,
        "priceChange24hr": 0.9262,
        "highLowDiff24hr": 1.2371999999999996,
        "weightedAvgPrice24hr": 15.00409339
      },
      "recommendation": {
        "toBuyOrNotToBuy": "Don't Buy",
        "volumeHeatRating": "Hot",
        "volumeRatio1minTo1day": null,
        "volumeRatio5minTo1day": null,
        "volumeRatio1minTo5min": 1.8537560612418464
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there some reason why this shouldn't work with compression? thanks!

Comment: `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED` means your compressed content is being corrupted. API Gateway can't handle binary content from Lambda unless it is encoded as base64 and flagged accordingly in the Lambda response so that API-GW can convert it back to binary and return it to the client... since the Lambda API is character-based, any octets in the gzip stream that don't correspond to valid utf-8 characters will be mangled. Capturing the Lambda response from the API Gateway logs should reveal whether the problem is that the intermediate base64 encoding isn't happening... or API-GW isn't decoding it.

Comment: Thanks! Just wondering, how would one `encode as base64 and flag accordingly`?

Comment: See [Output Format of a Lambda Function for Proxy Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format). Compare to what API Gateway writes to the logs.  I'm hoping to send you in the right direction, but don't have a solid answer, since I have deployed API-GW+Lambda integrations but I haven't used aws-serverless-express.

Answer (score 1):

When you enable gzip, the mime type need to be explicitly mentioned to awsServerLess Proxy.

```
const binaryMimeTypes = 'application/json';
const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app, null, binaryMimeTypes);
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: This was very helpful, solved my issue with ERROR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED